# Would This Code Output the Same Result?

Tags: java, loops

I'm reviewing for the AP Computer Science A exam, and the code I wrote is a little different from the answer. Do you think you could check if each outputs the same result?

> Objective: To remove a Cookie Order of a specific type from the CookieOrder ArrayList order, and return the number of boxes removed.
>   Please assume that all methods work as suggested.

Answer:

> ```
> public int removeVariety(String cookieVar)
> {
>  int boxesRemoved = 0;
>
>  for (int i = orders.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
>  {
>  if (cookieVar.equals(orders.get(i).getVariety()))
> boxesRemoved += orders.remove(i).getNumBoxes();
>  }
> ```
>
> return boxesRemoved;
>    }

What I put:

> ```
> public int removeVariety(String cookieVar)
> {
>     String cookieType = cookieVar;
>     int totalRemoved = 0;
>
>     for(CookieOrder boxes : this.order)
>     {
>         String type = boxes.getVariety();
>         int totalBoxesCookieOrder = boxes.getNumBoxes();
>         if(type.equals(cookieType))
>         {
>             totalRemoved += totalBoxesCookieOrder;
>             this.order.remove(boxes);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return totalRemoved;
> }
> ```

Would this still work? Alternatively, if you would like to grade me, here's the [scoring  rubric](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap10_comp_sci_a_scoring_guidelines.pdf) (question 1, part B). I appreciate the help; the test is tomorrow and I'm super nervous.

Comment: Run the code and check if it returns the same result or not. How hard is it to write a main method in a test class?

Comment: Your code would throw a ConcurrentModificationException at `order.remove` unless `order` happens to be some sort of blocking data structure. Iterate using an Iterator instead. From what I recall of my own AP CS test, this is a bit beyond the scope of the AP, however.

Comment: One of the skills you should be developing is how to make sure the code you write is correct. In "real life" there won't be anyone standing behind your shoulder. Try to think of a bunch of test cases and run them against the code you've written and the answer provided.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to write this by hand and the exam specifically mentions that you can't use an IDE or any other type of software to do so. I know I could have tested it, but it seemed so radically different from the answer. That, And I would have had to re-create the entire program, which I don't have most of the syntax of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this would throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're removing an item from the list while iterating over it.

A safe way to do this would be to use an *iterator*. [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is a built-in class that all collections (including `ArrayList`s) must provide. The iterator gives you a way to iterate over a list (much like the `for`-loop you use) but also allows you to safely remove an element from a collection.

Start by getting an iterator from the `ArrayList`'s `iterator` method. Like `ArrayList`, `Iterator` is *generic* – that is, it is an `Iterator<CookieOrder>`, not just an `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<CookieOrder> iterator = order.iterator();
```

The `Iterator` class has two key methods: `hasNext` and `next`. You want to check each item until there are no items left. Whenever you call `next`, you advance the iterator by one. Your code would look like this:

```
// Make sure there are still items in the array.
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    // Get the item.
    CookieOrder o = iterator.next();

    // do something with o
}
```

Specifically for your question:

```
Iterator<CookieOrder> iterator = order.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    // Get the boxes cookie order.
    CookieOrder boxes = iterator.next();

    // Perform the same check as before.
    String type = boxes.getVariety();
    int totalBoxesCookieOrder = boxes.getNumBoxes();
    if(type.equals(cookieType))
    {
        totalRemoved += totalBoxesCookieOrder;

        // Here's where we want to remove it.
        //
        // Instead of calling order.remove, we can use the 
        // "remove" method of the iterator. This is safe.
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

---

For the scoring rubric (part B):

- +1/2 for accessing an element of `this.orders` (although implicitly, with `boxes`)
- +1/2 for comparing `cookieVar` (`cookieType`) with the result of `getVariety()`
- +1 for comparing for all elements, with no out of bounds potential
- no points for removing (next three criteria, worth two points) because it will throw an exception
- +1/2 for declaring and initializing `totalRemoved`
- +1/2 for `getNumBoxes`
- +1/2 for correctly accumulating the total number with `+=` (although they may choose not to give you this point for the `ConcurrentModificationException`, but in my experience they only penalize for errors once)
- +1/2 for returning correctly

Total score: **4/6** for this part.

Keep in mind that that score is only for that part; extrapolating, your score for the question might be 6/9, which is **already higher** than the mean score (5.46). Also keep in mind that these are not graded linearly; i.e., getting 50% of the questions right is quite good.

Good luck on your test!

Comment: Could you please score my code? I know you don't have to but I would really appreciate it.

Comment: 2010, the link is in my question under scoring rubric.

Answer (score 3):

> Would this still work?

Your code would fail with a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are modifying the collection while iterating it.

The model answer avoids this by using indexing instead of an `Iterator` ... and working from the tail to the head of the list.

Another way to avoid the CME problem is to use an explicit iterator, and use the `Iterator.remove()` method to do the removal.  (That will work with an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, but some more exotic list types might return an `Iterator` that doesn't support `remove()` for some reason.)

Comment: Would you mind scoring my code anyway? I don't know if that means that I messed up that badly...

Comment: If I understand the rubric correctly, I think you should get 4/6 or 4.5/6 for that part.  But what I think is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Also, when you remove -- you shouldn't advance the loop index on that iteration. If your requirement is to remove more than one matching item, you need to deal with that.

Two forms of loops will have problems with that; The third form doesn't.

1. `for(a : b)` will suffer ConcurrentModificationException, and the loop index would be advanced incorrectly;
2. `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` or (in the reverse direction) `i--` won't suffer the exception, but elements will move when you remove the item; `i++` will advance the loop index incorrectly unless you compensate;
3. `Iterator<CookieOrder>` has a `remove()` method, which both compensates the loop index correctly & doesn't suffer ConcurrentModificationException.

Example:

```
Iterator<CookieOrder> it = orders.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    CookieOrder cand = it.next();    // 'candidate' for consideration/ removal
    if (cand.getVariety. equals( type)) {
        // Remove;  iterator.remove() handles the loop index correctly.
        boxesRemoved += cand.getNumBoxes();
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the reverse direction loop have a problem? It does not access any index whose contents will be affected by the remove.

Comment: You're right Patricia, provided that Items(I .. N) have already been processed, that removing Item(I) will be 'past' the loop index I and thus not affect iteration.  However an algorithm that needs to be explained & checked for correctness, is something to be more cautious of. Edited, thanks!